# Add a Page Screen is Visually Blank

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg

On one of my sites on a multisite install of wordpress I am having an issue where when I try to add or edit a page just a blank page loads.

The HTML of the page that should be there is present if you inspect the page and I am getting several of the follow JS errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerBlockType')
```

I have disabled all plugins and gone back to default theme twenty twenty, and the issue persists.

I'm not using any custom blocks as I did see that answer come up as a reason for this error when searching online. I am only using blocks from the built in Gutenberg block editor.

I am updated to the most recent version of wordpress and woocommerce.

I tried turning on WP_Debug in wp-config.php but that did not show any errors when attempting to add or edit a page.

If there is more information I can provide please let me know, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched in your database 'registerBlockType' ?

Comment: I just attempted using PHPMyAdmin to search all tables in DB for 'registerBlockType'. I tried finding the exact phrase as substring and the exact phrase as whole field. Both came up with zero results.


As I'm not sure which table to look in I used the search function in PHPMyAdmin instead of just querying the DB as I'm not proficient enough with SQL to know the query to write in this case.

Comment: Can you take a copy of your database can use with a fresh WordPress install? I suspect some plugin might have corrupted your core WordPress file. Also, can you edit your question and add your directory?